# Match whole word in a sentence that starts with specific letters

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, cpu-word

I'm tried to write PHP code for matching words by using letters, but my task is not satisfied by `strpos()`. I need to match the whole word which starts with the needle string.

```
$string = "How are you robin ?";
$searchletters = "yo";
```

Desired result: `you`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$re = '/\b' . preg_quote($searchletters, '/') . '\w*\b/';

preg_match($re, $string, $m);
echo $m[0] . "\n";
//=> you
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN5bD7/2)

Comment: thanks its working fine, but i need to search the words beginning from search text can i know how to do that.

Comment: ex- if i search "hor"- this two words returns "horecabedrijven ,anchor" but  i need first world only "horecabedrijven" which start with ""hor" thanks

Comment: ok sure, check updated answer. It will search a word from starting only.

Answer (score 1):

```
strtok(strrchr($string,$searchletters), " ");
```

Explanations:

**strrchr()**: finds the position of the last occurrence of a string within another string, and returns all characters from this position to the end of the string.

**strtok()**: which can be used to split a string into smaller strings (tokens) based on some separator(s). 
For more details and examples, see the [strtok PHP manual page](http://php.net/strtok)