# Regular expression in PHP for finding whole words

Tags: php, regex

I want a code in PHP with regular expressions that returns whole words for any matches. For example if search for `ac` I want it returns all words in a string that have `ac` in any part. i.e. if the String have `facebook` or `act` or `face` it returns all the words to me, I wrote this code but does not work properly.

```
$regx = "/\\b(\\S)*ac(\\S)*/iu"; 
    foreach($values as $value) 
    {
        echo $value."\n";
        preg_match_all($regx, $value, $matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        var_dump($matches);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is not a regex task! you can use a operation that checks the membership!

Comment: Related: [Match whole word in a sentence that starts with specific letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29431160/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will return all the words containing "ac" in the string.

```
$regx = "/\w*ac\w*/iu";
```

- \w* => 0 or more letters
- ac  => ac
- \w* => 0 or more letters again

Example :

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("/\w*ac\w*/iu", 'To be accurate, there are a lot of Stackoverflow accounts.', $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

This prints :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => accurate
            [1] => Stackoverflow
            [2] => accounts
        )
)
```

Comment: It has just one problem. In my code in PHP it returns every word 2 times. Do you have any idea about solving it?

It returns words one time for first \w* and one time for second one.You can see the result of var_dump in the following comment

Comment: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "nachdem"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "ach"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Feedback"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "nachdem"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "ach"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Feedback"
  }
}`

Comment: I removed the parenthesis in the regex. This solves the problem of duplication.

Comment: Yes, now it works. But can you explain me what is the role of the parentheses that causes duplication?

Comment: `$matches[0]` contains what the whole regex matched (`(\w*ac\w*)`).
`$matches[1]` contained what the parenthesis matched (`\w*ac\w*`).
Both extracted the same informations so the results were duplicated. To make it clearer : if you want to extract what is matched by the whole regex, you don't need parenthesis to select specific parts that you want to extract.